# Should we say 'ISS' or 'the ISS'?

Tags: discussion

I have been editing things like this:

> How are we getting stuff to ISS

into

> How are we getting stuff to *the* ISS?

Is it proper to do this, or is it right to just say 'ISS'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The International Space Station vs. International Space Station. I think that the former is better because ISS is not a name. If it was called Skylab then the latter would be correct. Grammatically the ISS is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I'll let this [XKCD "Snare" comic](http://xkcd.com/1243/) speak for itself:

[image]

:))